# About singular $\beth_{\alpha}$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Why are there cofinitely many regular cardinals of type $\beth_{\beta}$ below any given singular $\beth_{\alpha}$, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal?

Comment: Where did you see that claim?

Comment: http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/logic/teaching/2013SS/models_of_set_theory_1/Skript.pdf page 65, near the top, under "Case 2"

Comment: Do you mean "co*finally*? Because that's what's being claimed there (and is quite a different story) ...